# Outputting from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just trying to make my code more efficient!

```
ip = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']
err = []

for address in ip:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((address, 9999))
    if result != 0:
        err.extend(address)
print(err)
```

this is the output I receive:

```
['1', '.', '1', '.', '1', '.', '1', '2', '.', '2', '.', '2', '.', '2', '3', '.', '3', '.', '3', '.', '3']
```

if I run typecast to be either a float or int, there are errors thrown. I just need each ip address inserted into a list so I can print them out looking like:

```
1.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `err.append` to add strings rather than extend, which iterates the string to characters